# Databricks Subset all tables in a database

Tags: databricks

I have a databricks database and I want to subset all tables under this database for a specific set of values. Is there an easy way to do it instead of querying each table separately ?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you need to use **`catalog.listTables("<db_name>")`**

```
names = [(f.name) for f in spark.catalog.listTables("<db_name>")]

#show 100 rows of data from each table in the database
for i in names:
    spark.sql(f"select * from {db_name}.{i}").show(100,False)
```